# Symfony 2 Console command for creating custom Database

Tags: mysql, symfony, console, doctrine, dbal

I am working on a Symfony 2 project where each user have his own database. In my config.yml file I have a doctrine:dbal:orm set for a client but no connection properties because they are set at runtime and referenced by all users. I.e I only have one default dbal connection and two orm-connection and the amount of users is unlimited.

This works fine but I need to create the database and schema when the user is registered (FOS UserBundle). In the extended userbundle controller I can put my own logic.
The problem is that I cannot run the 'php app/console doctrine:database:create' since there are not parameters set for the new user.

Is there any way of specifying a custom database parameter to the console commands?
I could probably get around this by some very ugly mysql commands but I'd rather not.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can only pass connection but not parameters. Better you create your own command!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own command using the code below as an outline:

```
namespace Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;

class CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommandDynamically extends DoctrineCommand
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('doctrine:database:createdynamic')
            ->setDescription('Creates the configured databases');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
    /***
        **   Edit this part below to get the database configuration however you want
        **/
        $connectionFactory = $this->container->get('doctrine.dbal.connection_factory');
        $connection = $connectionFactory->createConnection(array(
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
         'user' => 'root',
         'password' => '',
         'host' => 'localhost',
         'dbname' => 'foo_database',
        ));

        $params = $connection->getParams();
        $name = isset($params['path']) ? $params['path'] : $params['dbname'];

        unset($params['dbname']);

        $tmpConnection = DriverManager::getConnection($params);

        // Only quote if we don't have a path
        if (!isset($params['path'])) {
            $name = $tmpConnection->getDatabasePlatform()->quoteSingleIdentifier($name);
        }

        $error = false;
        try {
            $tmpConnection->getSchemaManager()->createDatabase($name);
            $output->writeln(sprintf('<info>Created database for connection named <comment>%s</comment></info>', $name));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln(sprintf('<error>Could not create database for connection named <comment>%s</comment></error>', $name));
            $output->writeln(sprintf('<error>%s</error>', $e->getMessage()));
            $error = true;
        }

        $tmpConnection->close();

        return $error ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```